# How to implement Touch draw in iPad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, core-graphics

I want to implement a feature to take the signature from the user on the iPad screen.So i request you to suggest best available third party frameworks or source code where i can do it better rather than just drawing a line on screen.

Thanks in advance